# Custom dimension not showing on event page

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I have custom event sent from iOS App - `share` with parameter `type`
I created custom dimension for this parameter but when I open events detail page I can't see chart with custom dimension.

`type` parameter can have only couple of values - I have small enum for that in app code.

And Yes, I have waited nearly 24 hours for it t show up.

Comment: Please be more specific. I found this in the documents.
When you create custom dimensions and metrics, a data card for each one is added to the related event-detail report. However, it may take up to 24 hours for the data to appear. During this 24-hour period, you may see (not set) appear as a custom dimension or metric value. Once that initial 24-hour period has passed, you will see the expected values from that point forward.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209?hl=en

Comment: Yes, so I waited for 24 hours already and it did not show up.

Comment: I have same problem? Did you resolve that?

Comment: Waited some more and it appears.